# Enviar solo una vez un formulario con ajax o php

Tags: php, ajax, web

me podrian ayudar con ese problema porfavor, tengo un formulario tipo encuesta en donde el usuario al completarlo y luego enviarlo, solo pueda hacerlo una ves, no se si esto se pueda solo con el php o con ajax.

Comment: Puedes usar Ajax y desactivas el botón `Enviar` cuando el usuario haya pulsado sobre él. Pasando a algo más refinado, puedes mantener un control con información de la BD, donde no activas el botón si en la BD aparece registrado que ese usuario ya envió esos datos (lo digo para conexiones posteriores, o si ese usuario intenta desde otra ventana o desde otro cliente).

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta A. Cedano , pero lo que pasa es que son encuestas anonimas, no hay un proceso previo que ponga un numero de identidad solo muestra la preguntas defrente, tambien pense desactivando ajax pero quizas "magicamente" lo podrian burlar por ese medio.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *burlar*? Si son encuestas anónimas como dices, no hay nada que burlar, el usuario podrá enviar los datos las veces que quiera por cuanto es una encuesta anónima. A no ser que controles por IP por ejemplo, y aún así hay formas de enmascarar la IP para poder responder varias veces desde una misma conexión.

Comment: Saludos. Leyendo tu planteamiento y la respuesta que colocas respecto al primer comentario; es necesario algún elemento que te permita identificar quien ya respondió la encuesta. Un ejemplo es que seguro de algún servicio que maneje encuestas de calidad te llega a correo la misma para que la respondas y aun cuando no te logeas, la URL que te envían contiene elementos para identificar a quien fue dirigida y así saber si ya la concluiste.